# createAsyncThunk function is not getting called in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have to make application in react and reference app is https://www.griddynamics.com/services/global-team/outsourcing-calculator

Here below is the code that I have tried:
resourceSlice.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
const { createSlice, current, createAsyncThunk } = require('@reduxjs/toolkit');
const API_URL = "https://xxxx:xxxxxx@demo.xxxxxx.net/xxxx-2023/calapi"


// Thunks
export const fetchResuorces = createAsyncThunk('resources/fetch', async () => {
    console.log("In Fetch Resources by dispatch")
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            auth: {
                username: 'xxxx',
                password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
            }
        });
        console.log('response', response);
        return response?.data
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});

const resourceSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'resource',
    initialState: {
       rows: [{
        index: 1
       }],
       roles: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "rtype": "Engineers ( ASP.NET )",
            "experience": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "role": "High end Developer",
                    "rtypeId": 1,
                    "experience": 5
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "role": "Med level Developer",
                    "rtypeId": 1,
                    "experience": 2
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
    },
    reducers: {
        add(state, action) {
            state.rows.push({
                index: 2
            });
        },
        remove(state, action) {
            console.log('remove called')
            console.log(state.rows)
            return state.rows.filter((item, index) =>
                item.id !== action.payload
            );
        },
        getRoleLevels(state, action) {
            let selectedRoleId = action.payload;
            console.log(selectedRoleId)
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        console.log('extra builder')
        builder
            .addCase(fetchResuorces.pending, (state) => {
                console.log('Pending Response')
            })
            .addCase(fetchResuorces.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log('fulfilled')
                return action.payload
            })
            .addCase(fetchResuorces.rejected, (state) => {
                console.log('Call Rejected')
            })
    },
})


export const { add, remove, getRoleLevels } = resourceSlice.actions;
export default resourceSlice.reducer;
```

resource.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { add, remove, getRoleLevels } from '../store/resourceSlice';
import { fetchResuorces } from '../store/resourceSlice';

const ResourceComponent = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const resources = useSelector((state) => state.resource);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchResuorces)
    }, [])

    const handleAdd = () => {
        console.log("called handleAdd")
        dispatch(add())
    }

    const handleRemove = (index) => {
        console.log('index ID', index)
        dispatch(remove(index))
    }


    const getLevels = (roleId) => {
        //dispatch(getRoleLevels(roleId))
    }

    console.log('resources', resources)
    return (
        <>
            <div className="tab-content mt-5">
                <div className="mr-10">
                    <h3>Select resources you need</h3>
                    
                    {
                        resources.rows.map((resource, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className=" select-mode row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center" key={index}>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                        <select className="tech">
                                            { resources.roles.length > 0 && 
                                                resources.roles.map((role, roleIndex) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <option key={roleIndex} value={role.id}>{role.rtype}</option>
                                                    )
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </div >
                                    <div className="mb-3">

                                        <select defaultValue={resource.rtypeId} className="level">
                                            <option>Senior</option>
                                            <option>Intermediate</option>
                                            <option>Junior</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                        <select className="count">
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                        <select className="count">
                                            <option>Hour(s)</option>
                                            <option>Day(s)</option>
                                            <option>Month(s)</option>
                                            <option>Year(s)</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                        <input type="number" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mb-3">
                                        <button
                                            className="btn btn-cross btn-cross-yellow-dark remove-dev ml-2"
                                            onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}
                                        >
                                            <img src={props.crossSymbol} alt="remove" />
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    <button
                        id="add-position"
                        className="btn btn-link color-primary font-weight-normal plus-icon"
                        onClick={() => handleAdd()}
                    >
                        <img src={props.plusSymbol} alt="Add" />
                        Add a position
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ResourceComponent;
```

This is the folder structure as below:

[image]

Could anyone please let me know that

**#1** Can I use **reducers** and **extraReducers** at the same time, i.e. **extraReducers** for thunk function API call and **reducers** for internal state management like add or remove row?

**#2** Why **fetchResuorces** createAsyncThunk function is not getting call by default so that I get the values using API and display on components? Although console.log('extra builder') is printing in **extraReducers** snippet

Is there something code that I am missing, Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **#1** Can I use **reducers** and **extraReducers** at the same time, i.e. **extraReducers** for thunk function API call and **reducers**
> for internal state management like add or remove row?

Yes, you can absolutely use both internal reducers, e.g. `reducers`, and external reducers, e.g. `extraReducers`. The difference is basically that the `reducers` are for handling the actions the slice generates itself, e.g. `add`, `remove`, and `getRoleLevels` from the `resourceSlice` state slice, while the `extraReducers` are for handling any actions generated outside the slice. These extra reducer cases can be asynchronous Thunk actions or actions generated from other state slices.

> **#2** Why **fetchResuorces** createAsyncThunk function is not getting call by default so that I get the values using API and display on
> components? Although console.log('extra builder') is printing in
> **extraReducers** snippet

The issue here is that the UI code isn't actually dispatching the `fetchResuorces` action. The action needs to be invoked, e.g. `dispatch(fetchResuorces())` instead of `dispatch(fetchResuorces)`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchResuorces()); // <-- invoke fetchResuorces!
}, []);
```

The `console.log('extra builder')` is executed when the `resourceSlice` code is processed, e.g. when the app is mounting and the store is instantiated, so this is why you see that log without issue.